# Trying to print a Mathematical Table In a TextView. Its only printing last line of table?

Tags: android

```
  int n = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txt.getText()));

  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  {
      txtview.setText(n+" "+i+"s are "+n*i);
  }
```

The input is coming from an editText which is triggered by a button.

Here is the textview:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="264dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hey! what's up?"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
        android:lines="20"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: because you are setting only last line into textview

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    txtview.setText(n+" "+i+"s are "+n*i);
}
```

try this:

```
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sBuilder.append(n+" "+i+"s are "+n*i);
}
txtview.setText(sBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

each time you do

```
setText();
```

you replace actual text by the new thing. Use

```
setText(txtview.getText().toString()+ "n+" "+i+"s are "+n*i");
```

instead.

Or just make a big String, and display it after the loop :

```
String result="";
for(...) {
    result+="n+" "+i+"s are "+n*i";
}
txtview.setText(result);
```

Comment: second option is good, first create a single string of all data amd then set text. can you add that answer too?